# Hyperlink is not clickable on mobile, works fine on deskop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replace a caption in nextgen-gallery (WordPress plugin) lightbox with a hyperlink.
Hyperlink works just fine on desktop but unclickable on mobile.

Some element is blocking it in responsive mode but I can't seem to find it.

I've tried increasing the z-index, making entire div clickable by adding .attr('onclick',"location.href... Even tried image clickable.

All of above works in desktop mode and not in responsive. Could use a couple fresh pair of eyes before I give up.

link: http://cnc-kamieniarstwo.pl/index.php/galerias/

Original html:

```
<div class="sl-caption pos-bottom" style="width: 288px;">DSC_0366small</div>
```

Modified html, link is hidden behind some element in responsive, I can't seem to find:

```
<div class="sl-caption pos-bottom" style="width: 288px;"><a href="/form.php?id=DSC_0366small" style="clear:both;">Ask a Question</a></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: is http://cnc-kamieniarstwo.pl/index.php/galerias/ your website?

Comment: Not my site, but I do have ftp access

Comment: im just trying to find "Ask a Question" within your site

Comment: It redirects to a form where visitor can submit a question, nothing fancy, still work in progress...

Link just doesn't work in responsive mode... thats the problem

Comment: i didnt see <div class="sl-caption pos-bottom" style="width: 288px;"><a href="/form.php?id=DSC_0366small" style="clear:both;">Ask a Question</a></div> in your code on your site

Comment: when we click image on gallery, that image opens in a lightbox. This code belongs in  there.

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag and check 'javascript: void(0)'

Comment: Where to add this tag, any hints pls?

Comment: Use comments for this kind of info